# Is it possible to add a static footer to core-drawer-panel?

Tags: polymer

I am creating an app using the core-drawer-panel. The core-drawer-panel allows you to create the drawer and the main header. If I place any text after the `</core-drawer-panel>` it doesn't show up in the app so I am assuming everything needs to go inside the `<div class="content">` in order for it to be seen.

If I want to create a static footer like the topeka's status bar how would I go about doing that? Is it possible with core-drawer-panel?

Comment: Generally as per as guidelines when you have left side nav which will be invisible when you are using mobile view  you should create footer at the bottom of main section not at the bottom of both

Answer (score 2):

The footer needs to be inside the element that you've specified with core-drawer-panel's `main` attribute.

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

<core-drawer-panel>
  <core-header-panel drawer>
    ...
  </core-header-panel>
  <core-header-panel main>
    <core-toolbar>asdf</core-toolbar>
    <div fit>
      <footer>Sticky Footer!</footer>
    </div>
  </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dofiqiliyuxo/1/edit

Comment: Saved me, @ebidel! Polymer layout attributes FTW!

Comment: A friend says to avoid `position: fixed` as it has bad performance on mobile, and if you ever need multiple `fixed` it can be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Layout features](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html):

```
<style>
.content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
footer {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
</style>

<core-drawer-panel>
    <core-header-panel drawer>
        <core-toolbar>...</core-toolbar>
        <div> Drawer content... </div>
    </core-header-panel>
    <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar>Toolbar title</core-toolbar>
        <div fit vertical layout>
            <header>Top text</header>
            <div flex class="content">
                ...
            </div>
            <footer>Footer!</footer>
        </div>
    </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dabikurori/1/